# MySql Importing Database gives error

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

SQL query:

/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
MySQL said: Documentation

## 1231 - Variable 'character_set_client' can't be set to the value of 'NULL'

Comment: Any particular reason `@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT` wouldn't be null? What are you trying to do?

Comment: I am trying to import it into my server and it shows that error. And how can i change @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT from null to utf-8 or any other thing